# Mailbox Permissions/ AD Group Membership with Get-MailboxPermission

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

Is it possible to read AD Group Membership via `Get-MailboxPermission`?

Example: `Get-MailboxPermission 'mailbox@x.y'` returns Full Access Rights for the AD group 'MailboxXY'. I want to list the group members instead of the group names. How can I do that?

Comment: Pipe the group names into `Get-ADGroupMember`.

Comment: Get-ADGroupMember doesn't accept pipeline input of exchange mailbox objects.

Comment: Repeating myself: pipe the **group names** into `Get-ADGroupMember`.

Comment: @Dominik: Do what Ansgar is telling. Pipe all the groupname output to Get-AdGroupMember